# How to search specific value based on conditions using VLOOKUP in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to pass to function `VLOOKUP` the nearest value to cell `D242` as lookup_value. For example I have date `30.08.12` as lookup_value. If there is no value `30.08.12` then search for nearest value to 30.08.12 which is less than `30.08.12`. In this case it would be `29.08.12`.

```
    =VLOOKUP(D242;Table_crs.accdb[[Date]:[Sell]];3;FALSE)
Where 
    1. D242 is lookup_value
    2. Table_crs.accdb[[Date]:[Sell]] is table_array
    3. 3 is col_index-_num
    4. FALSE is [range_lookup]
```

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer (when you are able), and also accept it if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use `LOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP`, try either modifying your original formula by using TRUE as range_lookup, which will make it behave as you want, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(D242;Table_crs.accdb[[Date]:[Sell]];3;TRUE)`

.....or use LOOKUP like this

`=LOOKUP(D242;Table_crs.accdb[[Date]:[Sell]])`

Both of those formulas requires Date column to be sorted ascending (as does your suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

To use `LOOKUP` function as `lookup_value` argument for outer function `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(D243;Table_crs.accdb[Date]);Table_crs.accdb[[Date]:[Sell]];3;FALSE)
```

LOOKUP is used [because](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986)

> If LOOKUP cannot find the lookup_value, it matches the largest value
>   in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value.

Comment: Please move the whole of your answer to here from the question.